# How could I filter out codepoints before printing, which are not available on my computer?

Tags: perl, unicode, filter

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(utf-8)';

for ( 0 .. 10000 ) {
    print chr, ' ';
}
say "";
```

Is it possible to filter out the code-points in this loop before printing, which would be printed as spaces or rectangles. ( I tried to copy some rectangles as example, but here in the browser they transform to nice signs ).

Comment: Can you say something about where these are printing?  Like operating system, whether this is just output to a shell, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't know this. It’s a function of the fonts available in the program displaying the text. There’s no way for Perl to know what that program’s font-replacement strategy is.